# why my comparison between double fails c++

Tags: c++, comparison, double

i'm working on a project and to finish it i need to do some comparison with double, float ...
the problem is when i compare two double which are respectively the biggest value for a double and the biggest value for a double + 1, the comparison fail ... 
i do

```
if (std::max(d_max + 1.1, (d_max)) == d_max)
  std::cout << "bad" << std::endl;
```

the answer of the function max is d_max and "bad" is displayed ...
is anyone having an idea or a solution to get a good precision with my comparison ?
i checked on google but i found out more explanations than real solution to my problem ...
thanks so much !

Comment: It's unclear what you expect here. If `d_max` is the maximum value for a `double` then you're not going to get anything higher than it.

Comment: Maximum... <insert Inigo Montoya quotation here>

Comment: isn't it possible to compare the highest value of a double with another value without type ?

Comment: See http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 7):

All objects in C++ have a type. The type of `d_max` is `double`. The type of `d_max + 1.1` is still double. If `d_max` is the maximum value for a `double`, then `d_max + 1.1` is not representable and the closest representable value will be used, which is `d_max` (however, if you add a significantly larger value, the closest representable value is considered to be positive infinity). So your `std::max` call is equivalent to:

```
std::max(d_max, d_max)
```

To demonstrate:

```
double d_max = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
bool b = (d_max == (d_max + 1.1));
std::cout << std::boolalpha << b << std::endl;
```

This gives `true` as output.

---

In response to your comment, I assume you are doing something like this:

```
double d_max = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
long double ld = d_max + 1;
std::cout << (d_max == ld) << std::endl;
```

And strangely you find that apparently `d_max` and `ld` are equal. Why? Well `d_max` is a `double`. When you do `d_max + 1`, the result of the operation is also a `double` - the value of `d_max + 1` can't be represented in a `double` though, as described before, so the closest representable value (`d_max`) is chosen. This value is then assigned to `ld`.

Note that this isn't likely to be fixed by just making sure the operator results in a `long double` (perhaps with `d_max + 1.0L`). At such huge numbers (around `10^308` with an IEEE 754 representation), adding 1 will not move you along to the next representable value in a `long double`. With my implementation, I have to add 10<sup>289</sup> (that's 1 followed by 289 zeros) to actually cause a change in value:

```
double d_max = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
long double ld = d_max + 1E289L;
std::cout << (d_max == ld) << std::endl;
```

Also, there is no guarantee that `long double` has more precision than `double`. The only guarantee is that it doesn't have *less* precision.

Comment: i understand what you mean but even if i do the comparison without the max function and i compare a double with a long double which are havin respectively for value : max value of double and max value of double + 1, i get the same error than before ... that's what i don't understand. if i don't make any mistake a long double is bigger than a double isn't it ?

Comment: @bottus - don't assume that `long double` is bigger than `double`. Check it. Use `std::numeric_limits::max()`.

Comment: This isn't relevant: if the problem had to do with `d_max` being the largest value available, the result of the addition would be `inf` (as is the result of `d_max + d_max`). But it's not, the reason being insufficient significant digits as explained in my answer. − Ah I see you've added "will not move you along to the next representable value" now, that's the real answer.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think it's actually a bit of both. The fact there is no representable value greater than `d_max` means that that is the closest value and `1.1` was not enough to move it along any further. I covered both issues in my answer.

Comment: Certainly the range limit can be relevant in some implementation, but IEEE754-default specifies that a significant overflow in the addition would have to yield `inf`, which doesn't happen here.

Answer (score 1):

Let's pretend doubles are represented as decimal floating-point numbers, scientific notation. Then, `d_max` would be something like

```
9.999999999999999999 ⋅ 10⁹⁹
```

Now let's add `1.1` to that:

```
9.999999999999999999 ⋅ 10⁹⁹ + 1.1
= 999999999999999999900000000...000 + 1.1
= 999999999999999999900000000...001.1
```

round that to 20, or even 40 significant figures (which you have to as those types, even long double, have only finite information capacity) and you get...? well, `d_max` again.

---

Note that the same applies to subtraction as well, so

```
int main() {
  long double d_max = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
  if(d_max == d_max - 1.1)
    std::cout << "   d_max       = " << d_max
            << "\n== d_max - 1.1 = " << d_max + 1.1 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
   d_max       = 1.79769e+308
== d_max - 1.1 = 1.79769e+308
```

i.e. this really hasn't anything to do with `d_max` being the largest value available, but with it being so much larger than what you add to it.

Comment: okay, i understand well what you explained ;) the goal of what i'm doing is to manage underflow and overflow in my program. i need to do some operation like *, / ... ... the biggest operation i can do is the max value of a double * max value of a double. okay. but i want to manage the overflow to the assignation. i mean if i do a little test like double test = 1000000000000000; my program is not supposed to crash and i really don't have any idea of how to do it ... when i found the limits i think it would be enough but it seems to not be. do you know if it's possible to manage that?thank you

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: i'm trying to catch when there is a possibility of getting an overflow or an underflow. my project consist to do some operation between different type. when you try to assign a value to a type directly in your programm, your compilator don't let you do it. but i'm doing it with a file configuration like that                      float(2.324) double(5.15154) mul (for a multiplication) it's possible to put ridiculous value in the file and the compilator is not gonna see it, then i need to check before assigning if there is an underfor or overflow or not ;)

Comment: in fact what i want to do is simple (:D) i get a value like a string and a destination type, like 52655 int. what i want to do is check if the value correspond to the type and if not, throw an exception.

Comment: I see. Well, a somewhat stupid but reliable solution would be to try to parse the value as the desired type, then show it as a string again (e.g. with `std::stringstream`) and compare if that string is equal to the one you've read your value from. (Of course, that may get you in trouble with different representations of the same floating-point number.)